# How to observe the Application Context at runtime (while debugging)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, inversion-of-control

I am debugging my Java Spring service and I get an @Autowired variable as null, when it shouldn't be.

Since I have declared the service's class as @Service, I want to double-check that my bean was scanned by Spring and included in the Application Context.

Therefore, I want to be able to observe in Eclipse the contents of the Application Context.

How is this possible?

Comment: It cannot be `null`. If it is `null` you are creating bean instances yourself outside of the scope of Spring. Could very well be that spring has an instance but that isn't the one that doesn't get auto wired as that one is created by yourself.

Comment: Indeed, my constructor gets called. But it would be so cool to be able to observe the Application Context at runtime so that I can debug..

Comment: The fact that your constructor gets called doesn't say a thing. That could be scanned, that could be done by yourself. The fact that there even is an instance in the application context doesn't say a thing, because as soon as you start doen `new YourClass()` that instance is ignored. So in that regard inspecting the `ApplicationContext` doesn't say a thing either.

Answer (score 6):

inject `ApplicationContext` into a bean that you can debug and call `#getBeanDefinitionNames`

Comment: Hey @hahn thank you for your answer. Is there anything more elegant? Some solution through the IDE maybe?

Comment: yes, you can create a provider (helper) class which is ApplicationContextAware and create static methods for getting a bean. thus applicationContext would be injected into this class which you can then access by ACHelper.getApplicationContext() through out application

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround to get the `WebApplicationContext` in the debugger without changing the source code.

The `RequestContextUtils#findWebApplicationContext` method will help us with this.

You need to pass the current request to it, which can also be obtained using the static method:

```
((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest()
```

By combining these calls, you can get the context anywhere in the web application in the debugger and call any of its methods:

```
RequestContextUtils
    .findWebApplicationContext(((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest())
    .getBeanDefinitionNames();
```

Slightly prettier version:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = RequestContextUtils.findWebApplicationContext(request);
webApplicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the best way but without adding any extra framework,if you just want to check if dependencies are injected correctly or not ,you can firstly remove @Autowired annotation from the fields.

Now create a parameterized constructor and annotate the constructor with @Autowired. Spring will try to inject all the beans through the constructor.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_autowired_annotation.htm

Now you can put breakpoint inside the constructor to check what value is getting injected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To make things more confusing, the constructor gets called! And my autowired bean is still null! :/

Comment: You should use constructor injection anyway; even one of Spring's original developers is on record saying that @Autowired field injection is evil and he regrets its inclusion in the framework.

Comment: @E-Riz +1 I completely agree,it took me so much time in teaching juniors why we should not do Field Injections. Accessing even private Fields through reflection is a complete no-go for me.

Comment: @E-Riz how does the constructor injection work? I mean, I understand that the pre-compiler scans the annotations and knows when to run the autowiring (is my understanding correct?). If I autowire the constructor, how will the pre-compiler know where the bean gets declared if I don't initialize the bean?

Comment: @YiannisTsimalis Spring will take care of that. If you are calling a constructor and the dependency bean is still not created,spring will first create the dependency and then create the constructor

Comment: @AbhishekGarg what if I just declare the bean and not call it? Will the bean exist in the Application Context? And if yes, will its constructor be called? I don't think that the latter will happen..

Comment: First, there is no pre-compiler. All Spring injection is determined at runtime by the framework. Second, this answer *is* describing constructor injection. If you're following the advice in the answer, you're doing it. :-)

Comment: What to do you mean by declaring the bean,are you defining this bean in the applicationcontext.xml ? If yes then  spring will create all the beans defined in context xml

Comment: @AbhishekGarg I am using annotations. So, say that I write in a class e.g. User user and I want to see when the User will exist in the Application Context. Then, by autowiring the constructor (and not the user), won't the object appear in the Application Context when the constructor gets called? And won't the constructor get called if I instantiate the object through "new"?

Comment: Spring calls the constructors when the application context is getting created. You can either create Application context from an xml file ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app.xml") 
or web applications creates it when war is deployed. Now if you are manually calling a constructor you are bypassing spring so you will have to pass dependencies yourself to the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

you can use log4j.jar to output all the WARNINGS, DEBUGS, INFO once you start your server. Follow the below link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/logging_with_log4j.htm. I have a working example at my other laptop, can post the code. Let me know if you need it

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I know I can log, but I'd rather observe the Application Context through my IDE, not though logging. Is this not possible?